# Одинаковые данные при копировании в списке во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать копирование в списке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопки передают правильный index, index я передаю через `this.$root.$emit('copy', this.index)`
Родителей подхватывает и выполняет copy и по такому же принципу сделал increment & decrement

```
methods: {
  copy (index) {
    this.list.push(this.list[index])
  },
  increment (index) {
    this.list[index].score >= 10 ? false : this.list[index].score++
  },
  decrement (index) {
    this.list[index].score <= 1 ? false : this.list[index].score--
  }
},
```

Но какого-то хрена все значения одинаковые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не силен в фреймворке, что вы используете, но по коду похоже, что вы не копируете объекты, а копируете ссылки на объекты.

Думаю такой код поможет:

```
copy (index) {
  this.list.push(Object.assign({}, this.list[index]));
},
```

Только учтите, что Object.assign это ECMAScript 2015, если вы без бебеля, то используйте аналог из своей библиотеки.

Comment: Вы правы, я в реакте привык к { ... object } конструкции, а тут у готового сборщика не было ее, ставить мне не хотелось, а думать было слабо походу... Знал, что именно в этом проблема, но до последнего верил, что не так.